# LibreOffice Calc Macros - how to select/refer/access to an image in a sheet

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

Hy guys, I'm quite a newbie to LibreOffice. That's why I ask your help: basically I had inserted an image (.png) in my Calc sheet, image's name is "timber". I'd like to reposition it at some condition. The problem is that I do not find a way to select/refer/access to it by name, in order to get it moved. Any advice? Thank you in advance.

This was my attempt:

```
Sub moveImage
Dim oSel As Object
Dim oItem As Object
Dim aPosition As New com.sun.star.awt.Point

REM losing my religion!#?!

oSel = ThisComponent.getCurrentSelection()
If oSel.ImplementationName = "com.sun.star.drawing.SvxShapeCollection" Then
    oItem = oSel.getByIndex(0)
    aPosition.Y = 2200
    oItem.setPosition(aPosition)
Else
    MsgBox "Image not selected"
End If
End Sub
```

I guess I should add something at REM place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can't get an object by name, only `.getByIndex()`. But you can loop through all the items in your spreadsheet and check the name of each one:

```
Sub moveImage2
Dim oDrawPages As Variant, oDrawPage As Variant, oItem As Variant
Dim i As long, j As Long 
Dim aPosition As New com.sun.star.awt.Point
    oDrawPages = ThisComponent.getDrawPages()
    For i = 0 To oDrawPages.getCount()-1
        oDrawPage = oDrawPages.getByIndex(i)
        For j = 0 To oDrawPage.getCount()-1
            oItem = oDrawPage.getByIndex(j)
            If oItem.getName() = "timber" Then
                aPosition = oItem.getPosition()
                aPosition.X = 2200
                aPosition.Y = 2200
                oItem.setPosition(aPosition)
'  You can do Exit Sub now - but what about other images wih name "timber"? It may be several!
            EndIf 
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, thank you JohnSUN for the exit sub tip. It is exactly like you write, only getByIndex works. There's only one "timber" named image in my spreadsheet, so I do not need to worry.